# bytes[] not receiving at web api using HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient, httpwebrequest

I'm sending bytes[] to .net core web api method(from Windows application to web API) by using HttpClient with below code

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                // Pass the handler to httpclient(from you are calling api)
                HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");   // octet-stream");
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
                //client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/octet-stream");

                var content = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);
                content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                var response = client2.PostAsync("https://mywebsite.com/api/FileHandlingAPI/UploadFiles?filePath=abc", content).Result;
```

and web api method is

```
[Route("UploadFiles")]
        [HttpPost]       
        public ActionResult PostDataHello([FromBody]byte[] rawData,string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\WordAutomation\home.zip", rawData);                
                return StatusCode(200);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Error. msg: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

above code working while development but after hosting in server it is not working as expected. `var response` receiving 200 Statuscode but bytes[] not receiving at web api method.
any suggestions or changes required above code ?

Comment: You can use multipart to send byte data from your httpClient and then you can received byte data into `IFormFile` that would work.

Comment: Have you tried adding `[Consumes("application/octet-stream")]` to your controller method?

Comment: yes @SBFrancies, i tried, but  no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Content-Type` is set to JSON, which is invalid for uploading binary data in the payload.

Try

```cs
content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: tried with "application/octet-stream" also, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

> Above code working while development but after hosting in server it is
> not working as expected. var response receiving 200 Statuscode but
> bytes[] not receiving at web api method. any suggestions or changes
> required above code?

Well, not sure how are getting data on local server becuse, you are sending [MultipartFormData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa493937(v=exchg.140)) means your POCO object which is file path and byte array. As you may know we can send json object in FromBody but not the files as json. Thus, I am not sure how it working in local,  and getting null data is logical either in server like IIS Or Azure.

My take on this, for sending both POCO object and Files as byte or stream we need to use [FromForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources) and beside that, we need to bind our request object as [MultipartFormDataContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent?view=net-7.0) to resolve your null data on your PostDataHello API action.

**Required Change For Http Client:**

Http Client Request Model:

```
public class HttpClientReqeustModel
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] MyByteData { get; set; }
    }
```

Http Client Request:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendByteDataToAPIControllre()
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
            clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            //Bind Request Model

            var requestMode = new HttpClientReqeustModel();

            requestMode.MyByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\YourFile.pdf");
            requestMode.FilePath = @"D:\YourFilePath.pdf";
            requestMode.FileName = "YourFileNameYourWantToSet.pdf";

            //Create Multipart Request
            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            formContent.Add(new StringContent(requestMode.FilePath), "FilePath");
            formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(requestMode.MyByteData)), "MyByteData", requestMode.FileName);

            var response = await client2.PostAsync("http://localhost:5094/UploadFiles", formContent);

            return Ok();
        }
```

**Change For Asp.net Core Web API:**

API Model:

```
public class APIRequestModel
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public IFormFile MyByteData { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [Route("UploadFiles")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostDataHello([FromForm] APIRequestModel requestModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "WordAutomation/",requestModel.MyByteData.FileName);


                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await requestModel.MyByteData.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }
                // System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\WordAutomation\home.zip", rawData);
                return StatusCode(200);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Error. msg: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

For WinForm and WPF App:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
            clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            //Bind Request Model

            var requestMode = new HttpClientReqeustModel();

            requestMode.MyByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Md Farid Uddin Resume.pdf");
            requestMode.FilePath = @"D:\Md Farid Uddin Resume.pdf";
            requestMode.FileName = "MyFilename.pdf";

            //Create Multipart Request
            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            formContent.Add(new StringContent(requestMode.FilePath), "FilePath");
            formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(requestMode.MyByteData)), "MyByteData", requestMode.FileName);

            var response = await client2.PostAsync("http://localhost:5094/UploadFiles", formContent);
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @Farid, thanks for your time, I tried above code but it's not working and I'm calling web API from windows application,

Comment: `"But it's not working "` mean request doesn hit or getting null paramerter? What type of windows application, windows form or WPF?

Comment: Please have look on updated part, I have provided solution for Windows from and WPF app.

Comment: @Farid, i tried above one and i got "StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden'" then i added 'client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");', then i got status code 200 but file not created in server.

Comment: @Farid, any IIS level config required ?

Comment: Yes, add write access to IIS user which is `IIS_IUSRS`. You can [have a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights).