# How to call file upload (IFormFile) api in ASP.NET Core web api project from ASP.NET webform using WebClient?

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms, webclient, iformfile

I have created one API in ASP.NET Core 3.1 project for file uploading. This api working fine when I called api from Postman or any other .NET Core project using HttpClient. But I am unable to call this api from Webform using WebClient.

```
[HttpPost("Upload")]
public IActionResult Upload([FromForm] IFormFile fileUpload)
{
    ResponseViewModel responseModel = new ResponseViewModel();
    try
    {       
        if (fileUpload == null)
        {
            responseModel.Message = "Please select file.";
            return BadRequest(responseModel);
        }

        //file upload to temp folder
        string tempFilPathWithName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (FileStream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(tempFilPathWithName))
        {
            fileUpload.CopyTo(file);
        }
        UploadFile uploadFile = new UploadFile()
        {
            FileName = fileUpload.FileName,
            TempFilPathWithName = tempFilPathWithName
        };

        responseModel.Model = uploadFile;
        responseModel.Message = "File successfully uploaded";
        return Ok(responseModel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        responseModel.ExceptionMessage = ex.ToString();
        responseModel.Message = "File upload failed.";
    }
    return BadRequest(responseModel);
}

public class ResponseViewModel
{   
    public object Model { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; } 
}
```

After uploading file on server (where ASP.NET Core wep api project deploy) I will getting response like: uploaded file path and name.

Comment: `"But I am unable to call this api from Webform using WebClient."` How did you tried that? Share that code snippet.

Comment: You could [`try this way using httpclient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403325/bytes-not-receiving-at-web-api-using-httpclient-c-sharp/75406447#75406447) and most importantly process is same regardless of any .Net technology.

Answer (score 1):

> This api working fine when I called api from Postman or any other
> .NET Core project using HttpClient. But I am unable to call this api
> from Webform using WebClient.

It would be nicer if you could share your request code snippet in details but apart from this you could achieve the using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0).

In addition to this, sending file request from ASP.NET webform project you would require [MultipartFormDataContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent?view=net-7.0) so that you can implement your requirement accordingly.

> After uploading file on server (where ASP.NET Core wep api project
> deploy) I will getting response like: uploaded file path and name.

Let's have a look on a quick demonstration how we can efficiently implement that in action:

File Upload From ASP.NET webform To Asp.net Core Web API:

```cs
public partial class Contact : Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(UploadFileFromAspDotNetWebFormToWebAPI));
        }
            
        static readonly HttpClient client = Client.GetClient();
        private async Task UploadFileFromAspDotNetWebFormToWebAPI()
        {
            //Bind your file location
            var readFileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Md Farid Uddin Resume.pdf");
            //Create Multipart Request
            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(readFileData)), "fileUpload", "fileUpload");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7132/api/Upload/UploadFromWebFromToWebAPI", formContent);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ResponseViewModel readApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseViewModel>(readResponse);
            }

        }
       
    }
```

**Note:** Important point to keep in find here, in [StreamContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.streamcontent?view=net-7.0) you should match request parameter as same as your controller parameter defination. In your scenario, your controller name is **fileUpload**; Thus, it should be matched exactly and last one is file name you want to pass which is mandatory and I kept that same but you can put anything. Otherwise, request would not reach to endpoint.

Response Model:

```cs
public class ResponseViewModel
{   
    public object Model { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; } 
}
```

Output:

[image]

Last but not least, for API code snippet I have tested with your sample but I personally prefer following way and I like to keep my files under wwwroot.

[image]

API File Operation:

```cs
        [HttpPost("UploadFromWebFromToWebAPI")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFromWebFromToWebAPI([FromForm] IFormFile formFile)
        {

            if (formFile.FileName == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Files/", formFile.FileName);


            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }
            UploadFile uploadFile = new UploadFile()
            {
                FileName = formFile.FileName,
                TempFilPathWithName = path
            };


            var responseViewModel = new ResponseViewModel();
            responseViewModel.Model = uploadFile;
            responseViewModel.Message = "File Uploaded...";
            responseViewModel.ExceptionMessage = "N/A";
            return Ok(responseViewModel);

        }
```

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=net-8.0#system-net-http-httpclient-postasync(system-string-system-net-http-httpcontent))

Comment: Thanks for the positive response. your solution is working fine for me using HttpClient.

Comment: Gald to assist you on this. Is there anything else that I can assist with.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution to my question. Using the below code we call file upload (IFormFile) API in ASP.NET Core web API project from ASP.NET webform using WebClient.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class User : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath = @"C:\temp\excelsheet.xlsx";
                string apiToken = "BearerToken";
                
                NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
                headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), $"Bearer {apiToken}");
                List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>() { new FileInfo(filePath) };
                
                MultiPartFormUpload multiPartFormUpload = new MultiPartFormUpload();
                MultiPartFormUpload.UploadResponse response = multiPartFormUpload.Upload("https://localhost:5001/api/FileUpload/Upload", headers, new NameValueCollection() { }, files);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }       
    }
    
    public class MultiPartFormUpload
    {
        public class MimePart
        {
            NameValueCollection _headers = new NameValueCollection();
            byte[] _header;

            public NameValueCollection Headers
            {
                get { return _headers; }
            }

            public byte[] Header
            {
                get { return _header; }
            }

            public long GenerateHeaderFooterData(string boundary)
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                stringBuilder.Append("--");
                stringBuilder.Append(boundary);
                stringBuilder.AppendLine();
                foreach (string key in _headers.AllKeys)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(key);
                    stringBuilder.Append(": ");
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(_headers[key]);
                }
                stringBuilder.AppendLine();

                _header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());

                return _header.Length + Data.Length + 2;
            }

            public Stream Data { get; set; }
        }

        public class UploadResponse
        {
            public UploadResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string responseBody)
            {
                HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
                ResponseBody = responseBody;
            }

            public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; set; }

            public string ResponseBody { get; set; }
        }

        public UploadResponse Upload(string url, NameValueCollection requestHeaders, NameValueCollection requestParameters, List<FileInfo> files)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                List<MimePart> mimeParts = new List<MimePart>();

                try
                {
                    foreach (string key in requestHeaders.AllKeys)
                    {
                        client.Headers.Add(key, requestHeaders[key]);
                    }

                    foreach (string key in requestParameters.AllKeys)
                    {
                        MimePart part = new MimePart();

                        part.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"";
                        part.Data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestParameters[key]));

                        mimeParts.Add(part);
                    }

                    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                    {
                        MimePart part = new MimePart();
                        string name = "fileUpload"; //file.Extension.Substring(1);
                        string fileName = file.Name;

                        part.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
                        part.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream";

                        part.Data = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName));

                        mimeParts.Add(part);
                    }

                    string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
                    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

                    long contentLength = 0;

                    byte[] _footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

                    foreach (MimePart mimePart in mimeParts)
                    {
                        contentLength += mimePart.GenerateHeaderFooterData(boundary);
                    }

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    byte[] afterFile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");
                    int read;

                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        foreach (MimePart mimePart in mimeParts)
                        {
                            memoryStream.Write(mimePart.Header, 0, mimePart.Header.Length);

                            while ((read = mimePart.Data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                            mimePart.Data.Dispose();

                            memoryStream.Write(afterFile, 0, afterFile.Length);
                        }

                        memoryStream.Write(_footer, 0, _footer.Length);
                        var ss = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadData(url, memoryStream.ToArray());
                        string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                        return new UploadResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseString);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    foreach (MimePart part in mimeParts)
                        if (part.Data != null)
                            part.Data.Dispose();

                    if (ex.GetType().Name == "WebException")
                    {
                        WebException webException = (WebException)ex;
                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;
                        string responseString;

                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }

                        return new UploadResponse(response.StatusCode, responseString);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```